# Proof that $\int_K^{\infty} x p (x)\, dx = \int_K^{\infty} P (X> x)\, dx + K P (X > K)$

Tags: integration, probability-theory

Let $p(.)$ be a probability density function and $X$ a non-negative random variable, can we prove:
$$\int_K^{\infty} x p (x)\, dx = \int_K^{\infty} P (X > x)\, dx + 
 K P (X > K).$$

This is a generalization of the Tail Probability Expectation Formula for $K \neq 0$ but I could not find any mention of such a result.

Comment: The first term on RHS is not correct. The integrand does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Fixed X to x. Typo.

Comment: Still wrong. $P(x>K)=1$ for all $x >K$.

Comment: Cleaned it, sorry cut/paste.

Comment: $P(X>x)=\int_{(x, \infty)} p(y)dy$. Apply Fubini.

Comment: Done. it does work. Will post.

Comment: @BrianMoehring It is the survival function at K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align*}
\int_K^\infty xp(x)\,dx &= \int_K^\infty \int_0^x p(x)\,dt\,dx \\ &= \int_K^\infty \int_K^x p(x)\,dt\,dx + \int_K^\infty \int_0^K  p(x)\,dt\,dx \\ &= \int_K^\infty\int_t^\infty p(x)\,dx\,dt + \int_K^\infty Kp(x)\,dx \\ &= \int_K^\infty P(X>t)\,dt + KP(X>K)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I was using $x=\int_K^x 1 \, dt+K$ which may explain the discrepancy.

Comment: @Nero Ooops, you're right.  I've edited to correct, so it matches your question as posed now.

Comment: If you correct the first line to $x= \int_K^x 1 \, dt+K$ then we get the result.

Answer (score 3):

We write $x=\displaystyle\int_K^\infty 1_{x>u} du +K$.

\begin{align}
 \int_K^\infty x \,p(x) \,dx &= \int_K^\infty \left(\displaystyle\int_K^\infty 1_{x>u} du +K\right) \,p(x) \,dx \\
 &= \int_K^\infty\int_K^\infty 1_{x>u} du \,p(x)\,dx  +K \,\mathbb{P}(X>K)\\
 &\overset{\text{Fubini}}= \int_K^\infty \underbrace{\int_K^\infty 1_{x>u}\, p(x)\,dx}_{\mathbb{P}(X>u)} \,du  +K \,\mathbb{P}(X>K)
\end{align}